# Replace a range with php

Tags: php, str-replace, substr

I am trying to replace first 2000 characters of a string with null.

For example:

```
$content = "nvinveneuifnoimmio";
$my_result = "fnoimmio";
```

I mean that I want the first 10 characters to be removed or to be replaced with a space character in above example.

whats the easiest way to do it?

thanks

Comment: 2000? 10? space? null? your question could do with some work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substr()

```
$my_result = ' ' . substr($content, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

[substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is what you need. It will take a section of the given string, x characters from the start.

```
$content = "nvinveneuifnoimmio";
$my_result = substr($content, 10);
```

If you want to replace instead, you can use a combination of [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) and maybe [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php):

```
$content = "nvinveneuifnoimmio";
$characters = 10;
$my_result = substr_replace($content, str_repeat(' ', $characters), 0, $characters);
```